# Setting up a form on Ruby on Rails where there is only an email to submit on a homepage without using the Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to build a one page website where visitors will simply be able to submit their email address to be notified of the company's launch. The only goal in the database is to get an email (no name, etc). There is only one page visible at first, which is the homepage. If the user submits an email already in use, it sends the user to an error page. If the email is not in use, it sends the user to a success page. 
Here is what my user migration looks like :

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is what my user model looks like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Here is what my pages controller looks like:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
   render template: "pages/#{params[:page]}"
 end
end
```

Here is what home.html.erb looks like:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <%= f.text_field :email , id: "search", class:"search input" %> <br />
    <%= f.submit "yep", class: "submit input" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my user controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to 'pages/success'
    else
      redirect_to 'pages/error'
    end
  end
end
```

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'user/signup'
  root "pages#show", page: "home"
  get "/pages/:page" => "pages#show"
  resources :users
  resources :pages
end
```

When i run the code, it shows an error :

*ArgumentError in Pages#show*

*Showing /Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/app/views/pages/home.html.erb where line #16 raised:*

*First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty*

Comment: I think you didn't initialize @user object in pages#show controller. Please check back

Comment: How can i do that? should i add a ***def create*** to the pages controller with whats in the user controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Rails and REST convention you shouldn't put the form in home.html.erb instead do the following,

In your users controller add new method and your controller will look like below,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to 'pages/success'
    else
      redirect_to 'pages/error'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email)
  end

end
```

Now move your form to `new.html.erb` in users folder like below,

```
<%= form_for @user, url: users_path do |f| %>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <%= f.text_field :email , id: "search", class:"search input" %> <br />
    <%= f.submit "yep", class: "submit input" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And don't forget to add routes,

```
root "users#new"
```

Also, model user.rb should have uniqueness validation

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. It renders the page, but doesnt register the email in the database...

Comment: Processing by UserController#new as HTML
  Rendering user/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered user/new.html.erb within layouts/application (195.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 232ms (Views: 222.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

Comment: it doesnt say anything else when i click on the submit button... Its as if it doesnt understand the button

Comment: Is it enabled? Try removing that class: "submit input".

Comment: so i removed all the javascript of my buttons... It seems to be progress... when i click on submit i get this error : "Routing Error
uninitialized constant UsersController
"

Comment: Because you have typo in your controller, it should be UsersController instead of UserController, also your file name should be users_controller.rb

Comment: ok so i changed user to users in the controller and everything messed up. where else do i need to change it?

Comment: Firstly remove get 'user/signup' if you are not using it or else change it to get 'users/signup' and tell me what other errors are you getting?

Comment: actually, i just renamed my views file too and it worked! AAH, THE WHOLE THING WORKED! thank  you so much !

Comment: Where you have creted new.html.erb? It should be under users folder.You might have foldername user.

Comment: @KrupaSuthar Muje lagta hai, `root "users#new"` is not ideal route case, rest is great.

Comment: @ray That's only for redirecting users to that page on initial request

Comment: @KrupaSuthar Yup that is not a home page he may want, it is additional.

Comment: Please check the question, he has mentioned that it is an only one-page application that takes email in the form and creates user out of it.

Answer (score 1):

In your user model add

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email
```

this validate the uniqueness of the email you enter.
the creation of the new user will flag error if the email is already registered.

another method is to add_index while you migrate the user table.add the follow

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
     t.string :email
     t.timestamps
    end
   add_index :users, :email, unique: true
 end
end
```

make changes to the form

```
<%= form_with(model: @user, local: true) do |form| %>
```

and add `@user = User.new` in your show action

Comment: Thank you, but it hasn't solved the error... It still blocks at the first line of the form in the html

Comment: change to `<%= form_for :user, :url => { :method => :get, :action => :create} do |f| %>` and in your create controller `@user = User.new(params[:user][:email])`

Comment: other method  is to use `form_with` `<%= form_with(model: @user, local: true) do |form| %>` and add `@user = User.new` to the show action in user controller.

Comment: Thank you ! The page renders, but the 
```
if @user.save
      redirect_to 'pages/success'
    else
      redirect_to 'pages/error'
    end
``` 
doesnt work... I'm not sure what the error is... Also, i did Rails console and it shows that no users were saved

Comment: change `@user = User.new(:email => params[:email])` in your create action

Comment: It's the same... it renders the page but doesnt solve the problem

Comment: can u tell me the first line of the form which one are you using ??? form_for or form_with ???

Comment: <%= form_for :user, :url => { :method => :get, :action => :create} do |f| %>

Comment: `@user = User.new(:email => params[:user][:email])` add this to u create and please do check that the server log whether its going to create action or not?

Comment: page renders, but it doesnt register user... maybe its an sql problem? Could it be bacause im on sqlite3 and not postgres?

Comment: its not the problem.... here its messed up with flow... you need to make some changes in your flow

Answer (score 0):

In Pages#show controller add this

```
    def show
      @user = User.new
    end
```

Comment: Thank you, but its still the same error... It blocks on the first line of my form in the html

Comment: can you share your PagesController ??

Answer (score 0):

"First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty". It usually means you cannot have
`<%= form_for(nil) do |f| %>` 
or 
`<%= form_for([]) do |f| %>`.

In your case, @user is being set in Users#create which corresponds to create.html.erb in users folder in views.

But you are calling it in home.html.erb at which point it is nil as Pages#show does not have any info on @user.

You might have to re-align your flow by using the appropriate view/controller.